# Is it possible to view cards across projects by due date on Trello?

Tags: trello, calendar

Is it possible to view all cards across all boards by due date?

For example, is it possible to see in a single view what tasks, across all boards, need to be completed on a given day. Or do I need to look at each board individually?

Answer (score 5):

There isn't (currently) a way to do this inside Trello.  However, there is a third party application ([**Trello Calendar**](https://trellocalendar-francois2metz.dotcloud.com/)) that will allow you to do this.

Comment: Trello Calendar is no longer being hosted.

Comment: how do i see cards across all the boards was the question. I want to do the same thing. I already have the Calendar Power UP -> but it only works inside one trello board not across all my boards. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible but **not on Trello**.

You need to [sync Trello with Sunrise-calendar](http://help.trello.com/article/763-using-trello-with-sunrise-calendar), it can be done in 2 minutes and it's really powerfull.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. But only the cards that are assigned to you.

[image: filter cards by due date across boards in trello - step 1]
[image: filter cards by due date across boards in trello - step 2]

So in order:

1. click your "profile icon" in the upper right corner
2. click on "Cards"
3. from the horizonal menu in the next page -> select "Cards"
4. click the "first sorting option"
5. from the drop down that appears select "sort by due date"

Now this doesn't work if you are not assigned to those cards already, and that is exactly the feature I need - because for now I work alone - and adding myself to all cards, just to be able to filter on due date,  is such a time waster.
If anyone has a solution for my case let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, not yet, but such a feature [is being discussed](https://trello.com/card/sorting-a-list-by-vote-date-label-alphabetically-etc/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/486) in the Trello [Development board](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c)

Answer (score 0):

This has been added (I realize this question is rather old). Go to trello.com and click "Cards" on the bottom right.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Since the Trello card overview does not support a calendar, there is no feature to show all cards of all boards in Trello. But you can either use Sunrise or trello-calendar.w11k.de (open source).